# Is there a way to include when a file was last updated in bookdown?

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I have a bookdown book and I would like to include on each page the date when the source `.Rmd` file was last updated/modified.

I am aware one can get [when the file was compiled](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/update-date.html) with `Sys.Date()`, but I'm not sure of how to get this from the file properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file.info("filepath/filename.Rmd")$mtime

Comment: Just to beware - if you are pulling source data in, this wouldn't update if the data changes. If the source data is in a file, you could use it on both and use the greater value.

Comment: This is helpful; but do you know of any way to have this occur automatically?

So far I've added in functionality to run an R script on each page prior to knitting (similar to the `before_chapter_script` functionality, except that it can parse file details as well) which is appending the timestamp result to the end of each page.

Do you know if this can be achieved using standard bookdown methods?

Comment: The yaml header 'date' field would be my approach: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/update-date.html so:    date: "`r file.info('filepath/filename.Rmd')$mtime`" but if the question is really how to get that in a footer, it is no longer a how do I get the value question it's how do I edit the template...